# Updating child-records with their parents' attrs on create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, associations, nested-attributes

**In Rails, how can you update a child record with values from its parent before either the child or parent are saved?**

I'm using Rails' nested attributes to create a parent record with many children.  The parent record has a user_id attribute to track its owner, and for purposes outside of the scope of this question, the child record *also* needs to store this user_id attribute.

Currently, I'm using a before_save callback on the child model:

```
before_save   :set_user_id

def set_user_id
  if user = self.parent.try(:user) 
    self[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end
```

But because I also need to make sure that the child is unique for a given parent/user combo, I have to do this:

```
validates :parent, 
          :uniqueness => {:scope => :user_id}, 
          :unless => Proc.new{|child| child.user_id.blank?}
```

The problem is that `unless` parameter.  The child's `user_id` attr is blank until after validation, so the validation effectively isn't run on child creation.  This causes a problem if users double-submit the form; the result is that duplicate, invalid subscriptions end up in the database.  I've tried to fix this by changing this:

```
before_save   :set_user_id
```

to

```
before_validate   :set_user_id
```

but it appears the parent's user_id is not accessible before validation.

Has anybody encountered such a problem?

Comment: Just for the clarification: the parent may _not_ have a user? That's what `self.parent.try(:user)` tells me but you didn't mention it in your question

Comment: @Delba no, that means the parent may be nil

Comment: @ThongKuah uh that's basically the same thing... Just wanted to get confirmation by the asker because it influences the answer.

Comment: @Delba, no, the parent exist & have a user.  So that can be rewritten as `self.parent.user`

Comment: @trisignia I've tried the code on 3.0.x project, the parent and the parent's attributes is available to the child in before_validation. More-ever, if the parent is new too, you will still get a duplicate as parent_id will always be different. If the parent already exists, it seems that the child can only have the user_id from the parent always. So effectively, this limits the number of children for each parent to one anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

If possible, can you just put a hidden field in the form with the user_id in it? You'll probably need to do some validation and potential rollback in an after_save, but seems like it might be easy.

Another option might be to just set the user_id for all the relevant objects in the params hash in the controller before calling the save/create on the parent object.